# Visitor pattern with internal iterators

Tags: design-patterns, iterator, visitor-pattern

I'm trying to understand the following description of implementing the visitor pattern with an internal iterator. It is from the GoF's Design Pattern Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software book Page 339 (More context is provided below and in the [online version](http://www.cs.unc.edu/%7Estotts/GOF/hires/pat5kfso.htm)).

> The main difference is that an internal iterator will not cause
> double-dispatching—it will call an operation on the visitor with an
> element as an argument as opposed to calling an operation on the
> element with the visitor as an argument.

Can someone explain why I have to "call an operation on the visitor with an element as an argument"? I can come up with the following code to call the `Accept` operation on the element with the visitor as an argument, which supports double-dispatching:

```cpp
Node root = BuildTree();
CodeGeneratingVisitor visitor;
PreorderIterator i = root.CreateIterator();
i.ForEach([&visitor](const Node& node) {
    node.Accept(visitor); });
```

More context:

[image]

Comment: "why I have to "call an operation on the visitor with an element as an argument"?" - you don't have to; they are being a little handwavy there, but my guess here is that an *internal* iterator (where you'd do something like `root.TraverseWith(&visitor)`) can take advantage of the knowledge of the internal details of the object structure (where sub-elements with different concrete types may be stored separately), so it can invoke the concrete overload on the visitor itself. (BTW, they use the word iterator in the sense of iterator pattern, it doesn't have to be a C++ iterator).

Comment: Thanks @FilipMilovanović. I think the implementation would look like 

```c++
class ConcreteNode : public Node {
 public:
  virtual void TraverseWith(const Visitor& visitor) {
    visitor.Visit(this);
    for (const Node* child : children_) {
      child->TraverseWith(visitor);
    }
  }
 private:
  std::vector<Node*> children_;
};
```

This way the `TraverseWith` method still double-patches. The `Visit` call depends on the types of the Node and child. I think the description seems wrong. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: That's true if you have `std::vector<Node*> children_`. But, I think what they are getting at are cases where a node might store different subtypes of children separately. E.g., imagine a 3D scene (in a 3D modeling program) represented as a scene graph (where objects can be parented to other objects). A node might have `meshes_`, `cameras_`, `lights_`, etc., because some operations are type-specific. But you can select everything and move it: `scene.Accept(translateVisitor)`, and the node can internally do `for (const Camera* cam : cameras_)`, and pass it to visitor to avoid double dispatch.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I see. I guess the implementation may or may not use double-dispatch, and either calling style can be used. For example, the for loop can be implemented as either `for (const Camera* cam : cameras_) { cam->Accept(visitor); }` or `for (const Camera* cam : cameras_) { visitor.Visit(*cam); }` Both would work (assuming `Accept` doesn't recurse).

Comment: I think the author assumes `Accept` implements recursion. When an internal iterator visits the element, it can't do recursion because the iterator does the recursion. Thus, it has to call `Visit` on the visitor, not `Accept`.